# How can I change background color in every sunday using MBCalendarkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mbcalendarkit

I am using MBCalendarkit. How can I change background color in every sunday.

Comment: Please open CKCalendarCell.m file and go to applyColorsForState function and apply your some logic there for Sunday.

Comment: Please suggest me. Do you have any code or logic?